# How to locate an element In this case?

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation

I'm trying to locate an element that changes according to the selected item of the dropdown, but that's always on the same place... The code of the element that's not selected gets hidden, and when you select it gets visible and the previous gets hidden.

The code above is presented when you select one of the items and what seens like to change the other elements of the code is the `data-matricula` on the first line. Is it possible to extract the element that is on the last line (number 68) the same way for the different codes (that follows the same structure when I change the item selected of the dropdown)?

```
<div id="dashboard" class="left" data-matricula="6045511020" data-mc="313.5" data-mco="52.25">
<div class="left"><div id="main" class="content"><div class="header">
<i id="print" data-nb="6045511020"></i><h2>XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX</h2>
<ul><li class="numeric">75632</li><li class="numeric">Nasc.: 29/08/1964</li>
</ul></div><div class="features"><div class="group">
<label>Número/label><span class="numeric">6045511020</span>
</div><div class="group"><label>Concessão</label><span class="numeric">18/12/2018</span></div><div class="group">
<label>Agência</label><span class="numeric">UF:SC</span></div><div class="clear"></div>
<div class="group"><label>Tipo</label><span><b class="numeric">68</b>SIMPLIFICADO SPX</span></div><div class="clear"></div>
```

I noticed that the xpath changes only the first `div` number when I change the selected item.

```
/html/body/main[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/span/b
/html/body/main[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/span/b
```

Comment: can you share the url ? I think it is possible to extract the number using dynamic xpaths. Are you using selenium or lxml ?

Comment: Thank's man! I'v searched about dynamic xpaths and could be able to solve my problem :) I'm really new in programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what I'v done was search about dynamic xpaths, and then found a video where the guy shows how you can test your xpath while you'r figuring out what it is...

Using Chrome you can inspect the page and press CTRL + f to type some xpath inside the inspect window, so it will tell you if its working or not before you implement it in your code.

Hope It helps someone, hugs from Brazil!